# Prevent TinyMCE from removing span elements

Tags: tinymce

**Here is the problem demonstration**

You can try it here: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/SLcaab

This is TinyMCE default configuration

- less all the plugins
- with extended_valid_elements: "span"

1 - Open the Html Source Editor

2 - Paste this html into the Html Source Editor:

```
<p><span>Hello</span></p>
<p><a href="http://www.google.com">Google 1</a></p>
<p><a href="http://www.google.com">Google 2</a></p>
```

3 - Click update in the Html Source Editor to paste the html in the editor

4 - Remember there is a span around 'Hello'.

5 - Place your cursor just before Google 2 and press backspace (the two links should merge inside the same paragraph element).

6 - Look at the resulting html using the Html Source Editor.

**Result (problem)**: No more span in the html document even though we added 'span' to the extended_valid_elements in the TinyMCE settings.

**Note:** I removed all the plugins to make sure the problem is at the core of TinyMCE.

**Edit 1 - I also tried:** valid_children : "+p[span]" - still does not work

**Edit 2:** Only reproduced on WebKit (OK on Firefox and IE)

Comment: works in this fiddle iwth content already set,  maybe the span is getting lost when pasted

Comment: @Thariama What do you mean "with content already set"? Pasting is not the problem since, if you reopen the Html Source Editor after clicking the update button inside the Html Source Editor (step 3), the span is still there.

Comment: contetn alread set means it works using afiddle with the content placed in the init textarea

Comment: @Thariama I get it but, I'm pretty sure it only works because you tested it with a non WebKit browser, or not on Windows? See Edit 2. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: yes, i tested this with a non-webkit browser/Windows 7

Comment: @Thariama in tinymce release 4 .. it is still removing span tags...i mean span is valid html , html5 inline tag.. why tinymce removes that?

Comment: @vishalsharma: i am not much into tinymce4 yet, if there is a problem with the functionality file a bug report on the tinymce bug report site and/or write a post into the developement tinymce forum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running the newest version of TinyMCE? I had the opposite problem - new versions of TinyMCE would add in unwanted span elements. Downgrading to v3.2.7 fixed the issue for me, that might also work for you if you are willing to use an old version.

Similar bugs have been reported, see the following link for bugs filtered on "span" element:
http://www.tinymce.com/develop/bugtracker_bugs.php#!order=desc&column=number&filter=span&status=open,verified&type=bug

Comment: downgrading tinymce is a bad idea. the old versions won't work smoothly with new browser versions - this is the reason why the tinymce should be as up-to-date as possible

Comment: @Thariama is right. We can't just downgrade because we need some features/bugfix of the latest version. But you are also right, this is definitely a TinyMCE (major) bug in the 3.5.8 version :-(

Comment: Yeah, downgrading isnt a good idea - just a temporary solution while you hope for a fix in the next version. I guess the best you can do is report a new bug to the TinyMCE developers, or vote for fixing similar bugs. If you have the time you could try to track down whats causing it.

Answer (score 21):

Insert `extended_valid_elements : 'span'` into `tinymce.init`:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea.tinymce',
    extended_valid_elements: 'span',
    //other options
});
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it actually solves the problem using the options built into TinyMCE.

Comment: The original post said that he'd confirmed that this was already set.

Comment: This works, but it removes class from my span. I use instead this line of code, but it maybe allow some error elements:
valid_elements : '+*[*]',

Comment: Perfect answer. I also think that this should be the accepted answer. It would help a lot.

Comment: I used it, and it accepted the spans, but the problem then was it still removed all attributes of that span (in my case the class attribute). The solution in that case is to use:

`extended_valid_elements: 'span[*]',`

(so to add `[*]` behind the span).

Answer (score 11):

I have the same problem and I find solutions.  Tiny MCE deleted SPAN tag without any attribute.  Try us span with class or another attribute for example:

```
<h3><span class="emptyClass">text</span></h3>
```

In TinyMCE 4+ this method good work.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I hate this buggy editor but there are alway tons of legacy code to maintain :)

Comment: This works, but is not quite as good an answer as [Jangho Bae's answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35524890/302103) since that allows spans that do not have classes as well.

Comment: I am using tinymce 4.6.6 I have specified classes with my span tags but still this issue is not resolved

Answer (score 2):

Tinymce remove span tag without any attribute. We can use span with any attribute so that it is not removed.

```
e.g <span class="my-class">Mahen</span>
```

Comment: Annoyingly, you also have to add something in between the span tags. For example, I used a no break space or &nbsp; when I needed span elements without the text, such as using glyphicons.

Answer (score 2):

In the Tinymce plugin parameters enable:
Use Joomla Text Filter.

Be sure your user group have set "No filtered" Option in global config > text filters.

Comment: As this is a joomla anwer, are you sure this was a joomla question?

Comment: This worked for me, but only after I realized there are different configuration "Sets" on the Joomla TinyMCE plugin settings page. After I changed "Set 0" using your suggestion, which included administrators and editors, it started working. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this for 3.5.8:

1. Replace cleanupStylesWhenDeleting in tiny_mce_src.js (line 1121) with this::

   ```
    function cleanupStylesWhenDeleting() {
           function removeMergedFormatSpans(isDelete) {
                   var rng, blockElm, wrapperElm, bookmark, container, offset, elm;
                   function isAtStartOrEndOfElm() {
                           if (container.nodeType == 3) {
                                   if (isDelete && offset == container.length) {
                                           return true;
                                   }

                                   if (!isDelete && offset === 0) {
                                           return true;
                                   }
                           }
                   }

                   rng = selection.getRng();
                   var tmpRng = [rng.startContainer, rng.startOffset, rng.endContainer, rng.endOffset];

                   if (!rng.collapsed) {
                           isDelete = true;
                   }

                   container = rng[(isDelete ? 'start' : 'end') + 'Container'];
                   offset = rng[(isDelete ? 'start' : 'end') + 'Offset'];

                   if (container.nodeType == 3) {
                           blockElm = dom.getParent(rng.startContainer, dom.isBlock);

                           // On delete clone the root span of the next block element
                           if (isDelete) {
                                   blockElm = dom.getNext(blockElm, dom.isBlock);
                           }

                           if (blockElm && (isAtStartOrEndOfElm() || !rng.collapsed)) {
                                   // Wrap children of block in a EM and let WebKit stick is
                                   // runtime styles junk into that EM
                                   wrapperElm = dom.create('em', {'id': '__mceDel'});

                                   each(tinymce.grep(blockElm.childNodes), function(node) {
                                           wrapperElm.appendChild(node);
                                   });

          blockElm.appendChild(wrapperElm);
                           }
                   }

                   // Do the backspace/delete action
                   rng = dom.createRng();
                   rng.setStart(tmpRng[0], tmpRng[1]);
                   rng.setEnd(tmpRng[2], tmpRng[3]);
                   selection.setRng(rng);
                   editor.getDoc().execCommand(isDelete ? 'ForwardDelete' : 'Delete', false, null);

                   // Remove temp wrapper element
                   if (wrapperElm) {
                           bookmark = selection.getBookmark();

                           while (elm = dom.get('__mceDel')) {
                                   dom.remove(elm, true);
                           }

                           selection.moveToBookmark(bookmark);
                   }
           }


               editor.onKeyDown.add(function(editor, e) {
                   var isDelete;

                   isDelete = e.keyCode == DELETE;
                   if (!isDefaultPrevented(e) && (isDelete || e.keyCode == BACKSPACE) && !VK.modifierPressed(e)) {
                           e.preventDefault();
                           removeMergedFormatSpans(isDelete);
                   }
           });

           editor.addCommand('Delete', function() {removeMergedFormatSpans();});
   };
   ```
2. put an external link to tiny_mce_src.js in your html below the tiny_mce.js

Comment: Hacking the core is a terrible idea, especially in a project as complex as TinyMCE.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to use the work around by writing it as a JavaScript script which prevents WYSIWIG from stripping empty tags. Here my issue was with including Font Awesome icons which use empty <i> or <span> tags.

```
<script>document.write('<a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>');</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Came across this question and was not happy with all the provided answers.

We do need to update wordpress at some point so changing core files is not an option. Adding attributes to elements just to fix a tinyMCE behaviour also doesn't seem to be the right thing.

With the following hook in the `functions.php` file tinyMCE will no longer remove empty `<span></span>` tags.

```
function tinyMCEoptions($options) {
    // $options is the existing array of options for TinyMCE
    // We simply add a new array element where the name is the name
    // of the TinyMCE configuration setting.  The value of the array
    // object is the value to be used in the TinyMCE config.

    $options['extended_valid_elements'] = 'span';
    return $options;
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'tinyMCEoptions');
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having same issue. empty SPAN tags are being removed. The solution i found is

`verify_html: false`,