# 2sxc: Configure Tinymce to prevent removes empty span tags

Tags: 2sxc

It seems that tinymce removes empty span tags like already discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14962819/prevent-tinymce-from-removing-span-elements) one solution could be to insert in **tinymce.init** function the following option **extended_valid_elements: 'span'**. 
Is there a way to configure it in 2sxc?
If not, where can i find the js files of tinymce to manually configure it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment there is no central configuration for this. The config itself is currently done in https://github.com/2sic/2sxc-ui/blob/master/src/sxc-edit/fields/string/string-wysiwyg-tinymce.controller.js and is then minified/compiled into the dist-folder.

You can change it, but would have to keep an eye on keeping your changes "alive" when upgrading.

Comment: Thanks you will try this out! :)